# Door Detection in architectural floor plan

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project of rooms detection in a floor plan image,currently i'm able to extract walls from the image but stuck at doors detection.
I tried using arc detection but results are not good. Can someone suggest a better approach.

```
def door_detection(r_img):
   gray =cv2.cvtColor(r_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
   erosion = cv2.erode(r_img, kernel, iterations=3)
   dilated = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 3)
   blurred = cv2.medianBlur(dilated,5)
   canny = cv2.Canny(blurred,100,200)
   contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_TREE, 
   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   contour_list=[]
   for contour in contours:
      approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
      area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
      if ((len(approx) > 10 & (area > 100) ):
          contour_list.append(contour)

   cv2.drawContours(r_img, contour_list,  -1, (255,0,0), 2)
   cv2.imshow('dilated',dilated)
   cv2.imshow('Objects Detected',r_img)
   cv2.imwrite('arcs.jpg',r_img)
   if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Maybe you can try a recursive method: call the same function once for each wall, with different parameters for 'dilated', 'blurred' and 'erosion'?

Comment: can you provide an image sample ?